# how to repaint a jpanel with button click and also switch between 2 panels

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to repaint a panel with a button click, but its not happening. i tried using many methods like setEnabled(true), setVisible(true), repaint(), but none of these are working. And also i want to switch between two panels, like, if i click the "Total Vote" button, one panel should display, when i click on "Departmentwise Vote", another panel should display in the same place.

please help. Thanks in advance.

here i m providing the code :

```
public class RSummary extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame rframe = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5;
    JTable table;
    JScrollPane scroll;
    JSplitPane splitPane;
    JButton butx;

   public RSummary()
   {

    rframe.setSize(550,300);
    rframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    setSize(550,300);
        rframe.setTitle("Summary Report");

        /* Total Vote  & Department wise vote buttons */
           panel1= new JPanel();
          JButton but1 = new JButton("TOTAL VOTE");
          JButton but2 = new JButton("DEPTARTMENT WISE VOTE");
          but1.addActionListener(this);
          panel1.add(but1);
          panel1.add(but2);

          /* Report contents according to button */
          panel2 = new JPanel();
         String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Department","Phno","LUID","Select"};
        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
        model1.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model1); 
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel2.add(scroll);
        panel2.setVisible(false);


        /* close button */
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        JButton but4= new JButton("CLOSE");
        but4.addActionListener(this);
        panel3.add(but4);


        /* Page heading */
        panel4 = new JPanel();
        JLabel lab =new JLabel("VOTE SUMMARY REPORT");
        panel4.add(lab);


        /* dummy panel */
        panel5 = new JPanel();
        JButton butx = new JButton("Hello butx");
        panel5.add(butx);


    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, panel1, panel2);
    rframe.add(splitPane);
    rframe.add(panel3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    rframe.add(panel4,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    rframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    rframe.setVisible(true);

}  

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    { 
String action=ae.getActionCommand();

if(action == "CLOSE")
{
    rframe.setVisible(false);
}
if(action == "TOTAL VOTE")
{
    panel2.setVisible(true);  //this code is not working, i want the solution here. 
}

    }
   public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
   {
        new RSummary();

   } 
    }
```

Comment: *"how to repaint a jpanel with button click and also switch between 2 panels"*  Which is the one matter of the two you want answered here, now?  They are candidates for 2 questions with 2 [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch panels you can do:

```
rframe.remove (panelToRemove);
rframe.add(panelToShow);
```

Is this the answer to your question or why do you want to repaint?

Geosearchef

**UPDATE:**
To summarize:
MadProgrammer is right, you have to replace `if(action == "TOTAL VOTE")` by `if(action.equals("TOTAL VOTE"))` (same for CLOSE)

and you have to add an actionCommand:

```
JButton but1 = new JButton("TOTAL VOTE");
but1.addActionListener(this);
but1.setActionCommand("TOTAL VOTE");
```

To change panels:

```
if (action.equals("TOTAL VOTE")) {
    try{rframe.remove(panel1;)}catch(Exception e){}//clear window, maybe there is a method
    try{rframe.remove(panel2;)}catch(Exception e){}
    try{rframe.remove(panel3;)}catch(Exception e){}
    rframe.add(panel2);//the panel you want to show
}
```

Of course, you have to get references to the panels to `actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)`.

Comment: When the frame loads, there should not be anything, After clicking a button panel should get visible. As in my case, there are two button, when i click the first button, one panel should display, when i click on another button that time it should switch to another panel

Comment: Button 1: try {rframe.remove (panel1);}catch (Exception e){}    try {rframe.remove (panel3);}catch (Exception e){}     rframe.add (panel2);                    //for button 2 exchange the words panel2 and panel3 in the code

Comment: M not getting a clear picture, if u have the piece of code then it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is you're comparing the object references of your `String` values and not there contents...

```
if(action == "TOTAL VOTE")
```

Because of the way `String`s are managed by Java, it is very unlikely that these will ever be equal.

`String` comparison in Java is done using `String#equals`

```
if ("TOTAL VOTE".equals(action))
```

Your second problem may be related to the fact the `setVisible` may not be invalidating the container hierarchy, which would tell the layout framework that the containers need to be updated.

You have two solutions, the first would be to call `revalidate` on the parent container, the second, and better, would be to use a `CardLayout`, which is designed to just what you are trying to do...

Take a look at [How to use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

**Update after running the Code**

You have a series of compounding issues...

- You never set the action command of any of the buttons, so when the `actionPerformed` event is raised, the `action` is actually `null`
- `RSummary` extends from `JFrame`, yet you create a second `JFrame` called `rframe`.  This is very confusing and could potentially lead to more problems if you're not dealing with the correct frame.

Start by setting the `actionCommand` property of your buttons...

```
JButton but1 = new JButton("TOTAL VOTE");
but1.setActionCommand("TOTAL VOTE");
```

Then remove `extends JFrame` from `RSummary`, as it is doing nothing but adding to the confusion and adds no benefit

Setting a frame invisible will not "close" it.  Instead use `JFrame#dispose`

Finally, making a component visible while it's part of split pane won't resize the split divider.  Once you've made the corrections, you will need to manually move the divider.

You may consider placing a empty panel into the split pane and using a `CardLayout`, add the other components to it, switching them in and out using the `CardLayout`

**Updated with modified code**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class RSummary extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFrame rframe = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5;
    JTable table;
    JScrollPane scroll;
    JSplitPane splitPane;
    JButton butx;

    public RSummary() {

        rframe.setSize(550, 300);
        rframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setSize(550, 300);
        rframe.setTitle("Summary Report");

        /* Total Vote  & Department wise vote buttons */
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        JButton but1 = new JButton("TOTAL VOTE");
        but1.setActionCommand("TOTAL VOTE");
        JButton but2 = new JButton("DEPTARTMENT WISE VOTE");
        but1.addActionListener(this);
        panel1.add(but1);
        panel1.add(but2);

        /* Report contents according to button */
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Department", "Phno", "LUID", "Select"};
        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
        model1.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model1);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel2.add(scroll);
        panel2.setVisible(false);


        /* close button */
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        JButton but4 = new JButton("CLOSE");
        but4.addActionListener(this);
        panel3.add(but4);


        /* Page heading */
        panel4 = new JPanel();
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("VOTE SUMMARY REPORT");
        panel4.add(lab);


        /* dummy panel */
        panel5 = new JPanel();
        JButton butx = new JButton("Hello butx");
        panel5.add(butx);

        splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, panel1, panel2);
        rframe.add(splitPane);
        rframe.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        rframe.add(panel4, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        rframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        rframe.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String action = ae.getActionCommand();

        if ("CLOSE".equals(action)) {
            rframe.dispose();
        }
        if ("TOTAL VOTE".equals(action)) {
            panel2.setVisible(true);  //this code is not working, i want the solution here. 
            panel2.getParent().revalidate();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        new RSummary();

    }

}
```

Comment: it doesn't effect, i tried this also. if this is the case, then my other buttons should not work, but other buttons are working fine.

Comment: I tried with "if ("TOTAL VOTE".equals(action))" statement also, but its not working

Comment: @user2909960 Check the updates, I was able to get it running with these changes...

Comment: I came with this question with lot of research , even that card layout also. But i am getting confused. I have actually lot of thing in a single window,  i have a page heading, then i have a close button, and then i need two buttons and an empty panel which will be visible after those button click.   Would you please post the updated code which you have edited.

Comment: When i click on total vote, the panel is visible but split pane is not working. i have to manually move up the split pane to see the content.